# Is $\ln(x)$ ever greater than $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

Is $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \ln(x) \lt x$ a true statement?

Just wondering for some convergence related thing

Comment: True for $x > 0$, for $x \leqslant 0$, what would $\ln x$ mean?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Oh I see for $x\lt1$, $ln(x)\lt 0$ and for $ln(1)$ we equal $0$ and then we slowly climb up. So The answer is yes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given

$$
f(x) = x - \ln(x),
$$

then

$$
f'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x}.
$$

Extreme value for $f'(x) = 0$, so

$$
x = 1
$$

Note that

$$
f''(x) = \frac{1}{x^2},
$$

as $f''(1) = 1$ the extreme value is a minimum, whence $f(x) \ge f(1)$, thus

$$
f(x) \ge 1.
$$

Therefore $x - \ln(x) \ge 1 > 0$, whence

$$
\ln(x) < x.
$$

Comment: I like this, I think what people normally say is something like "Heavy machinery for the small problem"

Comment: A stronger equation is

$$
\ln(x) \le x - 1
$$

Comment: I think label "precalculus" preculdes the use of derivatives.

Answer (score 14):

First note that by [definition of $e^x$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) we have 
$$x< \underbrace{\frac{x^0}{0!}}_{=1}+\underbrace{\frac{x^1}{1!}}_{=x}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x$$ for every $x >0$. Now since $(\ln(x))'= \frac{1}{x}> 0$ for every $x> 0$ it is clear that $x \mapsto \ln(x)$ is [strictly increasing](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncreasingFunction.html), combining these facts shows
$$\ln(x) < \ln(e^x) = x,$$
for every $x > 0$.

Comment: This is very nice.

Comment: One further question(this may be much harder, I don't know). Is $\forall x, log(x)^4 \lt x$. I am sure it is by doing some computations, since for $x\lt 10$ the power decreases $log(x)^4$, and after that it never gets a chance to catch up.(Note: Here I mean $log_10$, and above I intentionally did mean $ln$

Comment: $\log_{10}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)} < \ln(x)$ for $x >1$ and $\log_{10}(x) \leq 0$ for $0<x \leq 1$.

Answer (score 5):

We can get a stronger result using the method shown by @johannesvalks. Let

$$ f(x) = x - e \ln x. $$

Then

$$ f'(x) = 1 - \frac{e}{x}. $$

The function $f(x)$ has a local maximum or minimum only when $f'(x) = 0$, namely at

$$ x = e. $$

We can show this is a minimum either by taking the second derivative or by examining
$f(x)$ at some other positive value of $x$.  Therefore, for all $x > 0$,

$$ f(x) = x - e \ln x \ge f(e) = 0. $$

That is,

$$ x \ge e \ln x. $$

You can use this fact to prove other things such as your statement in a comment
that $(log_{10} x)^4 < x$.

Comment: Just to add some motivation to this, see the graphs of all 3 functions [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+x+and+y+%3D+ln+%28x%29+and+y+%3D+e+ln%28x%29+from+0+to+5)

Comment: An excellent illustration, thanks!

Comment: Also, @Katie, if you're wondering where that rogue $e$ came from, carry out the exact same calculation with an arbitrary scale factor $a$. You'll get that the minimum must be at $x = a$; then if you stipulate that the minimum $f(a) = 0$, so that the graphs touch (and the inequality is sharp), you'll see $a = e$ drop out. So David's scaling is the best possible!