# How to solve $\ln(x) = 2x$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I know this question might be an easy one. but it has been so long since I solved such questions and I didn't find a an explanation on the internet. I'd like if someone can remind me.

I reached that $e^{2x} = x$, but didn't know how to continue from here. I remember something that has to do with bases and equalizing parameters, but how do I do that in this case?

Comment: Suppose that $f(x) = e^{2x}$ and $g(x)=x$. What is $f'(0)$ and $g'(0)$?

Answer (score 3):

Draw a graph. $\log x < 2x $

A proof is by noting that $\log x < 2x$ for $x < 1$ and then differentiating both sides to see that the LHS grows slower than the RHS.

Equivalently, $e^{2x} > x$

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^x\ge x+1$, we have
\begin{align}
e^{2x}&\ge(x+1)^2\\
&=x^2+2x+1\\
&=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34+x\\
&>x
\end{align}
so there are no solutions (because they can never be equal).

I like using $e^x\ge x+1$ rather than calculus.

Comment: For calc, just show that $y=e^{2x}-x$ has a minimum at $x=-\frac12\ln2,y=\frac12(1+\ln2)$ and is therefore positive everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This equation has no solution. To see it, note that [$\ln(x)<x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847034/is-lnx-ever-greater-than-x/847045#847045)$<2x$ for every $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to solve this for complex $x$:

The function $f(z) = ln(z)-2z$ has an essential singularity at 0 and by Casorati-Weierstrass takes every complex value infinitely many times. And therefore must have infinitely many complex solutions there.